# Issue when set a password without turn on numlock on Ubuntu app in the Windows OS

Tags: password, windows-subsystem-for-linux

After install Ubuntu app in the Windows OS.
I set a password as number "0" on the numpad. But i missed to turn on the "numlock"
How can I update a new password.
Thank you

Comment: It worked. Thank you @muru